# How do I specify where the ndkPath() method is?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle

I've been working on building my app in Unity for android, but gradle keeps giving me error. I've been debugging them with the help of ChatGPT, but I came to one error that it could not solve. Since Gradle is an android thing I opened the `build.gradle` file in android studio. The error that it returns is this:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':unityLibrary'.
> Could not find method ndkPath() for arguments [/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2023.1.0a20/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/SDK/ndk/25.2.9519653/] on project ':unityLibrary' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

I've gone in with android studio and installed the newest version of the sdk and components in the /AndroidPlayer subfolder, but somehow nothing seems to fix this. The part that the error is referring to is this:

```
android
    ndkPath "/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2023.1.0a20/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/SDK/ndk/25.2.9519653/"
    compileSdkVersion 33
    buildToolsVersion '32.0.0'
```

Line 94 is the line that starts with `ndkPath`. Does anyone know how to fix this? I've been trying for days but the documentation for android studio has not been very helpful and ChatGPT is pretty stumped on it as well.

Comment: The settings are under `Unity > Preferences > External Tools.`

Comment: If you have to configure a special NDK path I would assume you are still using the deprecated stand-alone NDK. Modern NDK versions have a fixed installation path within the Android SDK so you don't have to specify the NDK path anymore.